# how to attach to a TAP interface from two different processes

Tags: python, linux, networking, ioctl, tun

I have a tap interface created like this:

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user myusername
ip link set tap0 up
```

I then attach to `tap0` using python and another program written in C++

Python:

```
def tapAlloc(tapname, mode):
    tap = os.open('/dev/net/tun', mode | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    ifr = struct.pack('16sH', tapname, IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI)
    fcntl.ioctl(tap, TUNSETIFF, ifr)
    return tap
```

(Just for simulation) if I try to attach to tap0 twice:

```
f1 = tapAlloc('tap0', os.O_RDWR) 
f2 = tapAlloc('tap0', os.O_RDWR)
```

I get the error when I run this for `f2`:

```
fcntl.ioctl(tap, TUNSETIFF, ifr)
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

How can I attach to a tap interface from multiple processes ?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by attaching to the same tap interface multiple times?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone In my workflow, I create and `select()` on tap interfaces using this python script. Another process (c++ program) should attach to these tap interfaces. The c++ program would push packets on this tap interface. Py script would be listening (select-ing) on this interface, receive the packet and then send to another interface. For all of this to work, I will need to be able to attach to the same tap interface from my c++ program and py script.

Comment: I'm no tap device expert but this sounds like a misuse of tap devices.  Instead, perhaps, you should have two different but related devices and each program opens one of them.  Or maybe you shouldn't use a tap device here at all since it seems you don't actually want its capabilities (which is connecting a read/writeable device and a normal-ish network interface on the system).